# How to build with correct JDK using Ant

Tags: java, ant, build

I have followed a lot of guides on how to do this, but I am still getting an error. I want to build with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

but every time I run my script it is giving me an error saying:

"Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to C:Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112"

I have changed my environment variables and added a new
JAVA_HOME
with the path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112"

but it is still giving me an error. any idea why this isn't working? I am using an ant script and this is also on a windows remote desktop connection.

Comment: Show us the output of "set j" in the console.

Comment: >set JAVA_HOME 
Output: JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

Comment: Did you try enclosing the JAVA_HOME content into double quotes?

Comment: Changing the environment variable doesn’t immediately affect any open command windows.  Open a new command window and try running Ant there.

Answer (score 0):

> "Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to
>   C:Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112"

Looks like you forgot a backslash that this message contains `C:Program Files` instead of `C:\Program Files`